# Проект не компилируется при переходе на новую версию

Tags: unity3d

Перешел с 2020.1 на 2021.1.5ф1. После перехода проект стал компилироватся с ошибками. (Проект на ПК)

Вот несколько из них:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
 ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\UnityProject\Grand\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ext.nunit@1.0.6\net35\unity-custom\nunit.framework.dll'.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо в новой версии нельзя использовать ` в названии директории.